# problems with the old and new Contact API

Tags: android

here's a few things i couldn't figure out and could find anyone else 
posting them in the discussion:

1.
In the new API

ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions table does not really work for 
me:

when I try to insert a row into the table, it gives me this error:

> 07-13 14:20:09.399: ERROR/XXXXX(3074):
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   URI:
>   content://com.android.contacts/aggregation_exceptions,
>   calling user: ............

my code here:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID1, 

String.valueOf(oldRawContactId)); 

values.put(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID2, 

String.valueOf(newRawContactId)); 

values.put(AggregationExceptions.TYPE, AggregationExceptions.TYPE_KEEP_TOGETHER); 

mContentResolver.insert(AggregationExceptions.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

and I'm sure the two raw contact id exists.

2.in the old API:

when I create a group in Contact book, the name of the group is not shown(or not shown correctly)

here's the code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 

values.put(Contacts.Groups.SHOULD_SYNC, 1); 

values.put(Contacts.Groups.SYSTEM_ID, mGroupID); 

values.put(Contacts.Groups.NAME, mGroupTitle); 

mContentResolver.insert(Contacts.Groups.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

3.in the old API:

when I insert a custom IM contact method for a contact, the data is inserted and shown correctly, but user cannot edit the contact using the default contact app any more. If I remove the contact method, user can edit the contact again.

here's the code for inserting the contact method:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 

values.put(ContactMethods.PERSON_ID, newContactId); 

values.put(ContactMethods.KIND, Contacts.KIND_IM); 

values.put(ContactMethods.TYPE, ContactMethods.TYPE_CUSTOM); 

values.put(ContactMethods.AUX_DATA, ContactMethods.encodeCustomImProtocol(MYIM_PROTOCOL)); 

values.put(ContactMethods.DATA, buddyId); 

values.put(ContactMethods.ISPRIMARY, 0); 

values.put(ContactMethods.LABEL, IM_LABEL); 

mContentResolver.insert(ContactMethods.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Answer (score 2):

AggregationExceptions don't support insert or delete, only update. Do an update and it will, "just work." The javadocs explain this:

> Constants for the contact aggregation
>   exceptions table, which contains
>   aggregation rules overriding those
>   used by automatic aggregation. This
>   type only supports query and update.
>   Neither insert nor delete are
>   supported.